# How to call set or get a Controller's config property from a view?

Tags: extjs, view, controller, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a controller something like this:

```
Ext.define('DigitalPaper.controller.Documents', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

views:  ['Documents'],
stores: ['Documents'],
models: ['Documents'],

config: {
  defaultColumnSet: undefined  
},....
```

I want to call the method getDefaultColumnSet or setDefaultColumnSet **from the view**.
Is this possible?

I have tried with

```
     Ext.app.Controller.getController('Documents');
```

But it doesn't work!

Any suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to call controller methods from a view. It's possible, but if you're trying to use MVC paradigm - I would avoid doing it.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Agreed.  Your controller should push the default column set to the view via the view's initial configuration or a method the view provides for the controller to call.

Comment: I would get the properties (config properties like "defaultColumnSet" in the example above) from the view, usually this is a very common procedure in MVC paradigm... any suggests?

Comment: This is not common procedure. Again - you're not explaining _why_ exactly do you need this. I understand you need to get property, but what are you gonna do with it and why do you need it? What's the underlaying logic?